# Sonarqube c++ syntax error skip __namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, sonarqube

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.  Sonar-scanner analysis is successful but these warnings are printed on the screen.  The team, being very new to Sonar and I, not knowledgeable enough in C++, are both stumped.

Sonar-scanner message:

```
WARN: [/home/jenkins/workspace/Sonar/LIS/src/CORE/CCPARSE/lib/Factory.C:39]: syntax error, skip '__namespace'
```

for other files containing the namespace block, everything in the namespace block are displayed as syntax errors.  Files without the namespace block are fine. The team needs the namespace blocks.

The actual code in Factory.C:

```
#include <CCPARSE/Factory.H>

namespace CCPARSE {
```

Needless to say, if I comment out the namespace line and its closing brace, the warning goes away.
The file is analyzed in Sonar though.  I can see the file mentioned in the analysis as well as a calculation of duplicated code, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a wise gentleman on GitHub, I figured out the issue.  namespace is a functionality of [C++ and not of C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396140/why-doesnt-ansi-c-have-namespaces) .  Once I renamed the files as .cpp instead of .C, the syntax error went away!