# Function with same names in different files - C

Tags: c

I have two functions with same name and want to use it in my application.

I referred various answers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728777/c-execute-function-from-different-files-with-the-same-name) and here but couldn't get clear solution.

I have following functions

```c
// xxxx_input.h

int8_t input_system_init(InputParams params);

int8_t input_system_easy_load(uint32_t interval_ms);
```

```c
// yyyy_input.h

int8_t input_system_init(InputParams params);

int8_t input_system_easy_load(uint32_t interval_ms);
```

Reason there are two files is `xxxx_input` and `yyyy_input` work way different internally.

Modifying the function isn't easy since the code is provided by external party and we have to keep the xxxx_input files.

What we can do is modify `yyyy_input.h` but functions like `input_system_easy_load` are to be kept consistent as they are called from different places.

Is there a way we can achieve the same?

I tried replacing `xxxx_input` with `yyyy_input.h` but since the include directory already contains the same function it gives error.

input_system_init multiply defined (by xxxx_input.o and yyyy_input.o).

Comment: You can not use both in the same compilation unit.

Comment: So I would suggest changing the name, even if it’s a hassle.

Comment: C function names always end up in a global scope (if they need to be called from different translation units), so if you need both to be built, you will need to rename one or the other.

Comment: Given what you have in hand, is it a better option to just compile two separate binaries and run them one after the other (possibly by the same script/job) or are those workflows truly dependent on each other?

Comment: @possum you think that is easier than renaming one of them? ^^

Comment: @Fredrik ^^  Could be given "Modifying the function isn't easy since the code is provided by external party" and keeping the code clean and separated.  I have no idea without seeing more or knowing the problem, but having worked in similar situations sometimes solutions like that  turn out to be the path of least resistance.  Given what's presented, do you think it couldn't be?

Answer (score 8):

If you have the source code to the functions defined in `xxxx_input.h` and `yyyy_input.h`, you could compile both modules with command line options redefining the function names via the preprocessor:

```
gcc -Dinput_system_init=xxxx_input_system_init -Dinput_system_easy_load=xxxx_input_system_easy_load xxxx_input.c
gcc -Dinput_system_init=yyyy_input_system_init -Dinput_system_easy_load=yyyy_input_system_easy_load yyyy_input.c
```

You would then compile your code with modified prototypes and you could link all 3 modules together.

If the modules are provided in object form only, you could define wrapper functions `xxxx_input_system_init` and `xxxx_input_system_easy_load` that you would link with the xxxx_input.o to produce a dynamic library, and the same for the `yyyy` alternatives. You would use modified prototypes in your module and would link it with the dynamic libraries.

Mike Kinghan showed a [simpler approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61958966/4593267) for object files and libraries on systems where `objcopy` is available.

To get modified prototypes automatically, you can use this include file:

**my_input_system.h**:

```c
#define input_system_init  xxxx_input_system_init
#define input_system_easy_load  xxxx_input_system_easy_load
#include "xxxx_input.h"
#undef input_system_init
#undef input_system_easy_load

#define input_system_init  yyyy_input_system_init
#define input_system_easy_load  yyyy_input_system_easy_load
#include "yyyy_input.h"
#undef input_system_init
#undef input_system_easy_load

/* prevent direct use of the redefined functions */
#define input_system_init       do_not_use_input_system_init@
#define input_system_easy_load  do_not_use_input_system_easy_load@
```

Answer (score 8):

I'll walk through a solution you can use if your supplier has given you object files compiled
with GCC or Clang for GNU/Linux computers.

My supplier has given me a header `foo_a.h` file that declares function `foo`

```
$cat foo_a.h
#pragma once

extern void foo(void);
```

and the matching object file `foo.o`:

```
$ nm foo_a.o
0000000000000000 T foo
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U puts
```

that defines `foo`.

Likewise they've given me a header `foo_b.h` that also declares `foo`

```
$ cat foo_b.h
#pragma once

extern void foo(void);
```

and the matching object file `foo_b.o`

```
$ nm foo_b.o
0000000000000000 T foo
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U puts
```

that also defines `foo`.

The functions `foo_a.o:foo` and `foo_b.o:foo` do different
things (or different variations of the same thing). I want to do both these things in the same program,
`prog.c`:

```
$ cat prog.c
extern void foo_a(void);
extern void foo_b(void);

int main(void)
{
    foo_a();    // Calls `foo_a.o:foo`
    foo_b();    // Calls `foo_b.o:foo`
    return 0;
}
```

I can make such a program as follows:

```
$ objcopy --redefine-sym foo=foo_a foo_a.o prog_foo_a.o
$ objcopy --redefine-sym foo=foo_b foo_b.o prog_foo_b.o
```

Now I have made a copy `prog_foo_a.o` of `foo_a.o` in which the symbol `foo` is
renamed `foo_a`, and a copy `prog_foo_b.o` of `foo_b.o` in which
the symbol `foo` is renamed `foo_b`.

Then I compile and link like this:

```
$ gcc -c -Wall -Wextra prog.c
$ gcc -o prog prog.o prog_foo_a.o prog_foo_b.o
```

And `prog` runs like:

```
$ ./prog
foo_a
foo_b
```

Perhaps my supplier has given me `foo_a.o` within a static library `liba.a`
that also contains other object files that refer to `foo_a.o:foo`? And similarly
with `foo_b.o`.

That's OK. Instead of:

```
$ objcopy --redefine-sym foo=foo_a foo_a.o prog_foo_a.o
$ objcopy --redefine-sym foo=foo_b foo_b.o prog_foo_b.o
```

I will run:

```
$ objcopy --redefine-sym foo=foo_a liba.a libprog_a.a
$ objcopy --redefine-sym foo=foo_b libb.a libprog_b.a
```

and this will give me a new static library `libprog_a.a`
in which `foo` is renamed `foo_a` in all the object files in the
library. Similarly `foo` is renamed `foo_b` throughout `libprog_b.a`.

Then I'll link `prog`:

```
$ gcc -o prog prog.o -L. -lprog_a -lprog_b
```

Consider a potential drawback with this solution. Possibly my supplier has
given me `foo_a.o` and `foo_b.o` with debugging information in them, and I want to
used it for debugging my `prog` with `gdb`?

I have changed the original symbol names, `foo_a.o:foo` to `foo_a` and
`foo_b.o:foo` to `foo_b`, but I haven't changed the debugging info associated
with those symbols. Debugging with `gdb` will still work, but some of the
debugging output will be incorrect and possibly confusing. E.g. if I put
a breakpoint on `foo_a`, `gdb` will run to it and stop, but it will say
it has stopped at `foo` from file `foo_a.c`. And if I then breakpoint at `foo_b`, `gdb` will run to
it and again say it is at `foo`, but from file `foo_b.c`. If the person doing
the debugging doesn't know how the program was built, this would certainly be
confusing.

But giving you debugging info with binaries is not far from giving you the
source code, so as you haven't got source code you likely don't have
debugging info and are not concerned about it.

Comment: What an elaborate answer! Thanks

Comment: Great alternative and more generic than preprocessor based renaming! Combine with my approach for the header files and it will be easier to account for modifications in the prototypes and/or other definitions in `foo_a.h` and `foo_b.h`. UV