# Use type defined in C library in C++ program with namespace like scheme

Tags: c++, c, types, namespaces

I have written a C library which defines some functions and types like the following:

```
typedef struct {
  int i;
} A;
void func1(void);
int func2(A* a);
```

I now want to use these functions and create variables of type `A` in a C++ program. Unfortunately C does not have namespaces but I would still like to emulate some similar structure to avoid name collisions in the C++ program. However I don't like the option of prepending every function and struct with a prefix:

```
typedef struct {
  int i;
} library_A;
void library_func1(void);
int library_func2(A* a);
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28535585%20) nice way to emulate a namespace scheme by defining a struct which has some pointers to the functions:

```
/*interface.h*/
struct library {
    void (*func1)(void);
    void (*func2)(A*);
};

extern const struct library Library;
/* end interface.h */

/* interface.c */
#include "interface.h"

void func1(void)
{
   ...
}
void func2(A* a)
{
   ...
}

const struct library Library = {
    .func1 = func1,
    .func2 = func2,
};
/* end interface.c */

/* C++ program */
#include "interface.h"

int main(void)
{
    Library.method1();
    A a;
    a.i = 5;
    Library.method2(&a);
    return 0;
}
/* end C++ program */
```

Is it possible to also include the definition of type `A` in `Library` or a  different way such that a type `Library.A` is defined in the C++ program and I can write the C++ program as

```
#include "interface.h"

int main(void)
{
    Library.method1();
    Library.A a;
    a.i = 5;
    Library.method2(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, it's not possible to do this.

> However I don't like the option of prepending every function and struct with a prefix

That is the proper way of handling this situation, though. Think about it this way: namespaces work as prefixes too, the difference is that instead of underscore `_` you use double colons `::`.

Your approach of using a `Library` global is surprising from a user's perspective. As a user my first question would be:

> > Is there a technical reason why I *shouldn't* use the library functions directly?

If there isn't a reason besides you, the developer, simply not liking how `library_XYZ` looks, then my next thought would be:

> > Pointless weirdness. The library developer doesn't take this seriously or is inexperienced.

And another thing, it will be extra work for you to maintain the library helper `struct` whenever you add, remove or rename stuff from the library. It will eventually become a burden to update that global.

Comment: There is also another problem: Address of `Library.func` cannot be used to initialize function pointer with static storage duration by library user, but `library_func` can be. This limits how library can be used.